# Fetch latest data using Ehcache in Hibernate using Java

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

I'm wondering why Ehcache is fetching the latest data whenever I change something in my DB. As per the documentation of Ehcache, it should fetch only after a certain time interval. Am I correct?

Here is my ehcache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<ehcache>  
 <defaultCache   
  maxElementsInMemory="100"   
  eternal="false"   
  timeToIdleSeconds="120"   
  timeToLiveSeconds="200" />  

  <cache name="com.sch.Employee"   
  maxElementsInMemory="100"   
  eternal="false"   
  timeToIdleSeconds="5"   
  timeToLiveSeconds="200" />  
 </ehcache>
```

My entity class

```
package com.sch;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;


    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(String name, float salary) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   
}
```

Is my understanding correct? If not, what's exactly running behind the scenes of EHcache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TTI` and `TTL` are the ones which decide the eviction process.

`timeToIdleSeconds – The maximum number of seconds an element can exist in the cache without being accessed. The element expires at this limit and will no longer be returned from the cache. The default value is 0, which means no TTI eviction takes place (infinite lifetime).`

`timeToLiveSeconds – The maximum number of seconds an element can exist in the cache regardless of use. The element expires at this limit and will no longer be returned from the cache. The default value is 0, which means no TTL eviction takes place (infinite lifetime).`

[Source](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/configuration/data-life.html)

As per the definitions defined, the seconds which you have for Employee

```
 <cache name="com.sch.Employee"   
  maxElementsInMemory="100"   
  eternal="false"   
  timeToIdleSeconds="5"   
  timeToLiveSeconds="200" />
```

If you don't access the employee record with in 5 seconds of the deployment, it fetches from the database.

Any how, even the TTL is 200 sec, which is regardless of use.

So Make TTL - 0, TTI - 3600 and retest the application.

By this, TTL eviction will not take place and TTI is one hour so you have time to test your application

Comment: No. For the first time it shows 104 ms to fetch, but from next time it shows 2,3 1 ms etc. Which is not correct, right?

Comment: 104 ms points to database retrieval and rest is from cache, I suppose. There may be browser cache as well involving in when you use GET. Are the timings changed or is that tested as is ?

Comment: Yes, the time elapsed is changed from 1st time to rest. I mean when I git the API again and again

Comment: When you want to check the updates pushing to cache in time interval, increase the time interval. Yes, the data is from cache and not database, it is behaving as expected.